# Understanding Generics and Reflection in Java to Make Array Generic

Tags: java, arrays, generics, reflection

I am trying to model a train with a Java program.

Currently I have four classes:

- `Train`,
- `BoxCar`,
- `Cargo`,
- `Person`.

The `BoxCar` class has an array of `Person` and an array of `Cargo`. A `BoxCar` can only hold one type so when that type is given from the constructor,

I decide which array to use (either the people array or the cargo array). The thing is, I'd like to make that array inside `BoxCar` "generic" so that if there is another "kind" of type the user wants to use, it can be easily set.
They wouldn't need to declare another array inside the `BoxCar` class for that type and change the rest of the code.

How would I do this? I looked up Generic and Reflection but the examples I saw weren't exactly for my scenario and I'm learning this for the first time. 
Can someone map out the right approach to take?

BoxCar:

```
class BoxCar {
    String boxType;
    int boxID;
    int count;
    boolean isEmpty;
    Cargo cargo[];
    Person people[];
    int capacity;

    BoxCar(String box_type, int ID, int cap) {
        boxType = box_type;
        boxID = ID;
        isEmpty = true;
        count = 0;
        capacity = cap;
    }
}
```

Person:

```
class Person {
    String government_ID, name;
    int age;

    Person(String gov_ID, String Name, int Age) {
        government_ID = gov_ID;
        name = Name;
        age = Age;
    }
}
```

Cargo:

```
class Cargo {
    String cargo_ID;
    int height, weight;

    Cargo(String c_id, int w, int h) {
        cargo_ID = c_id;
        height = h;
        weight = w;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code please!

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Yes, just added it

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question previously. Here is what it should be:

```
public class BoxCarContents {
    ...
}

public class Person extends BoxCarContents {
    ...
}

public class Cargo extends BoxCarContents {
    ...
}

public class BoxCar<E extends BoxCarContents> {
    E[] contents;

    public BoxCar(int capacity) {
        contents = new E[n];
    }
    ...
}

//Alternative way
public class BoxCar {
    BoxCarContents[] contents;

    public BoxCar(BoxCarContents[] boxContents) {
        contents = boxContents;
    }
    ...
}
```

Basically the `<E extends BoxCarContents>` means E can be anything that extends BoxCarContents.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm not sure what would be inside of the BoxCarContents class. Could you please help me understand that? Thank you

Comment: If all you want to do is make sure the only things in the boxcar can be people and cargo, and you don't intend to do anything with it, you don't have to put anything inside the class definition. You can just leave it empty.

Comment: I tried coding your solution but the compiler is complaining about the BoxCar constructor. Inside of it I have "contents = new BoxCarContent<box_type>[capacity];" 
How should I set the array inside of BoxCar if the syntax I just put in quotes isn't correct?

Comment: The main errors are:
 error: type BoxCarContent does not take parameters
error: cannot find symbol - Basically anytime I try to reference the gov_ID, cargo_ID, or any other member variable of either the Cargo or Person class, inside of the Train class, that error appears

Comment: Actually you can just make it simpler by making BoxCar non-generic, and giving it a field of type BoxCarContents.

Comment: Could you please edit your code to show that so I can see?

Comment: I just changed it

Comment: actually, how would I declare a Person object in my main with the new syntax added at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you out

```
public class Train {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Train();
}

public Train() {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("foo", "bar"));
    BoxCar<Person> personBoxCar = new BoxCar<>(persons);

    List<Cargo> cargo = new ArrayList<>();
    cargo.add(new Cargo("test"));
    BoxCar<Cargo> cargoBoxCar = new BoxCar<>(cargo);
}}

public class Person {

private String name;
private String surname;

public Person(String name, String surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}}

public class Cargo {

private String cargoType;

public Cargo(String cargoType) {
    this.cargoType = cargoType;
}

public String getCargoType() {
    return cargoType;
}}
public class BoxCar<T> {

private List<T> myArray;

public BoxCar(List<T> myArray) {
    this.myArray = myArray;
}}
```

Comment: A code dump with no explanation is not a useful answer.

Comment: Well, as soon as it gets more complicated I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

**The best way to accomplish that is using generics.**

Generics are a facility of generic programming that were added to the Java programming language in 2004 within version J2SE 5.0. They were designed to extend Java's type system to allow “a type or method to operate on objects of various types while providing compile-time type safety”

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

The generic `E` allows passing a type according to your needs.

```
class BoxCar<E> {
    private int boxID;
    private int count;
    private boolean isEmpty;
    private E target[];
    private int capacity;

    public BoxCar(int ID, int cap) {
        boxID = ID;
        isEmpty = true;
        count = 0;
        capacity = cap;
    }

    public setTarget(E target[]) {
        thid.target = target;
    }
}
```

**Another approach is to use interfaces, for example this could be a solution:**

Implementing an interface allows a class to become more formal about the behavior it promises to provide. Interfaces form a contract between the class and the outside world, and this contract is enforced at build time by the compiler. If your class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that interface must appear in its source code before the class will successfully compile.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BoxCar<String, String> boxCar_1 = new BoxCar<>(new Person("gov_id", "name", 35), 1, 1);
        BoxCar<String, String> boxCar_2 = new BoxCar<>(new Cargo("c_id", 1, 1), 1, 1);
    }
}

/**
 * This interface declares the
 * methods for box targets.
 *
 * @param <T> for jey
 * @param <E> for value
 */
interface BoxCarTarget<T, E> {
    /**
     * This method returns the data regarding to
     * a specific BoxCar target.
     *
     * @return Map with specific data.
     */
    Map<T, E> getPayload();
}

class BoxCar<T, E> {
    private BoxCarTarget<T, E> target;
    private int boxID;
    private int count;
    private boolean isEmpty;
    private int capacity;

    BoxCar(BoxCarTarget<T, E> target, int ID, int cap) {
        this.target = target;
        boxID = ID;
        isEmpty = true;
        count = 0;
        capacity = cap;

        /*
         * Here you can handle the payload.
         * I think we can use reflection for
         * extracting data.
         */
        Map<T, E> payload = this.target.getPayload();
    }
}

/**
 * Class person
 */
class Person implements BoxCarTarget<String, String> {
    private String government_ID, name;
    private int age;

    Person(String gov_ID, String Name, int Age) {
        government_ID = gov_ID;
        name = Name;
        age = Age;
    }

   /**
    * This method returns the data regarding to
    * a specific BoxCar target.
    *
    * @return Map with specific data.
    */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getPayload() {
        Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap<>();
        payload.put("government_ID", government_ID);
        payload.put("name", name);
        payload.put("age", String.valueOf(age));

        return payload;
    }
}

/**
 * Class Cargo
 */
class Cargo implements BoxCarTarget<String, String> {
    private String cargo_ID;
    private int height, weight;

    Cargo(String c_id, int w, int h) {
        cargo_ID = c_id;
        height = h;
        weight = w;
    }

   /**
    * This method returns the data regarding to
    * a specific BoxCar target.
    *
    * @return Map with specific data.
    */    
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getPayload() {
        Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap<>();
        payload.put("cargo_ID", String.valueOf(cargo_ID));
        payload.put("height", String.valueOf(height));
        payload.put("weight", String.valueOf(weight));

        return payload;
    }
}
```

**Hope this helps!**